# Mocking method with runnable arguments that return void

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

This is the interface of the method:

```
void startWatch(MethodToWatch methodName, UUID uniqueID, Runnable toRun);
```

This is the implementation:

```
public void startWatch(MethodToWatch methodName, UUID uniqueID, Runnable toRun) {
        this.startWatch(methodName, uniqueID);
        start();
        toRun.run();
        stop();
    }
```

i would like to mock this method with something like this:

```
IPerformanceStopWatch mock = mock(IPerformanceStopWatch.class);
when(performanceStopWatchFactory.getStartWatch()).thenReturn(mock);
when(mock.startWatch(any(), any(), any())).thenAnswer(new Answer<void>() {
    @Override
    public void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
        Runnable torun = (Callable)args[2];
        torun.run();
        return;
    }
});
```

the problem is that when(...) cannot get a method with return value of void.

how can i moke this method without using spy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `doAnswer()`:

```
// It is supposed here that Mockito.doAnswer is statically imported
doAnswer(...).when(mock).startWatch(etc);
```

You can just reuse the answer you have, which is good.

Comment: Uh? It has always worked for me. How didn't it work? What is your test?

Comment: had another problem :) seems like it is working :) thanks!